# Generic way to access elements of sequential sequences

Tags: c++, generics, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to write generic code for targeting C arrays, C++ libraries, and C++ standard library?

Example: dot product

```
template<class Vector1, class Vector2>
constexpr auto dot_product(Vector1 const& v1, Vector2 const& v2) {
  // doesn't work for Vectors that do not implement () subscripting
  using return_type = decltype(v1(0) + v2(0)); 
  return_type tmp = return_type{};
  // doesn't work for e.g. std::tuple
  for (std::size_t i = 0, e = size(v1); i != e; ++i) {
    tmp += v1(i) * v2(i);
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

- There is a problem with access the elements:

  - for a C array `array[i]`, C matrix `array[i][j]`
  - for a C++ `std::vector`, `vector[i]`
  - for a C++ `tuple`, `std::get<i>(tuple)`
  - for a C++ linear algebra vector/matrix (e.g. Eigen): `vector(i)`, `matrix(i, j)`
- There is a problem with iteration:

  - run-time for loops for C arrays, `std::vectors`, ...
  - `boost::fusion` for e.g. `std::array`, `std::tuple`, ...
  - custom expression for linear algebra libraries that handle both cases under the covers (e.g. Eigen uses expression templates)
- Boost.Geometry uses a `get` function to solve the access problem which results in convoluted code full with `get`s everywhere. It also uses strategies for dispatching the different iteration methods.

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: _Generic access_ Are you talking about indexing `operator[]()` overloading?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not necessarily, but mostly yes.

Comment: What do you mean by `(i.e. [i, j] is allowed but [i][j] is not)`. This isn't correct.

Comment: @Simple _for user defined types_. I've emphasized this and added operator infront of the array access to make it more clear.

Comment: @gnzlbg you can't make `[i, j]` valid for user-defined types. This is the comma operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i've reformulated the question to try to make it more clear, did it help?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with policy based template.

```
template <typename T> 
struct DefaultUsePolicy {
    int DoSomethingWithT( T const & ) {
        return 42;
    }
};
template < typename T, typename UsePolicy = DefaultUsePolicy<T>>
int Generic( T& arg ) {
    UsePolicy use;
    return use.DoSomethingWithT(arg);
}
```

Then have some default implementation for common type and let the user write a policy if he have a custom type.

The Generic function will document the services need in the policies it requires.

It is similar to what is done with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::default_deleter` to provide control on the destruction of the pointer owned.

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap the `get` function inside a class, something like:

```
#define Return(ret) decltype ret { return ret; }

template <typename T>
class Getter
{
private:
    T& t;
public:
    constexpr explicit Getter(T&t) : t(t) {}

    constexpr auto operator () (std::size_t i) const
    -> Return((get(t, i)))

    constexpr auto operator () (std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const
    -> Return((get(t, i, j)))

    operator T&() const { return t; }
};

template <typename T>
Getter<T> make_getter(T&t) { return Getter<T>(t); }
```

And then

```
template<class Vector1, class Vector2>
constexpr auto dot_product(Vector1 const& v1_arg, Vector2 const& v2_arg) {
  auto v1 = make_getter(v1_arg);
  auto v2 = make_getter(v2_arg);
  using return_type = decltype(v1(0) + v2(0)); 
  return_type tmp = return_type{};
  for (std::size_t i = 0, e = size(v1); i != e; ++i) {
      tmp += v1(i) * v2(i);
  }
  return tmp;
}
```